# How to wait till all nested functions are executed

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have a function which is getting data from url as stream and then I am using pipe to write this data in file using fs.createWriteStream. I want when file is created then it should return something. My current implementation is not waiting for file creation and returns immediately. Here is the snippet

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const axios = require("axios");

const FileUploadPath = "./uploads/";

const downloadFile = async (url, filePath) => {

    const writer = fs.createWriteStream(filePath)

    const response = await axios({
        url,
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'stream'
    })

    response.data.pipe(writer)

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        writer.on('finish', async function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log("file downloaded")
            resolve(filePath)
          }

        )
        writer.on('error', reject(null))                
    });


}

const file_resolvers = {
    Query: {
        async file_download(parent, args, context, info) {

            const fileUrl = // some file url
            var filePath = // path where downloaded file will be saved 

            console.log("Downloading File " + fileUrl);
            const result = await downloadFile(fileUrl, filePath);
            console.log("Result received: " + result);

       },

    },

};


module.exports = {
    file_resolvers,
}
```

I am getting "file downloaded" message after "Result received: null". Which means it does not wait for "finish" to get complete and returns with null immediately.

Comment: Code you posted is not sufficient to understand the problem..

Comment: @kgangadhar I have updated my code... full code given now